# Passing class object to a WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, oop

How can I  pass a class object 'obj' of the class ' BL_Customer' from my Web application to a function 'Insert()' in my Webservice (ASMX) and then access the properties of that object in the Webservice?. I have included my remote webservice by 'Add WebReference' facility. I have included 'using WebRererence;' namespace also. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my  BL_Customer class in Business Layer:

```
public class BL_Customer
{
    public BL_Customer()
    {

    }  
    string c_Cust_Name = string.Empty;    
    string c_Mobile_no = string.Empty;    
    public string Cust_Name
    {
        get { return c_Cust_Name; }
        set { c_Cust_Name = value; }
    }  
    public string Mobile_no
    {
        get { return c_Mobile_no; }
        set { c_Mobile_no = value; }
    } 

}
```

This is my Data Access Layer:

```
public class DAL_Customer
{
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    WebReference.Service objWEB = new WebReference.Service();  //objWEB -> Webservice object
    Connection c = new Connection(); 
    public DAL_Customer()
    {
    }
    public int Customer_Insert(BL_Customer obj)
    {
      ---------
      ---------
        return objWEB.Insert(obj);  // Insert() is a function in my remote webservice 
    }
}
```

This is my webservice:

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{   
   public Service () {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string insert(**What should be here?**)
    {
        -----
        -----

    }
}
```

Regards,
David

Comment: ASMX web service or WCF?

Comment: @UnhandledException asmx

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the technology you are using to build your web service there might be different ways to achieve this. If you are using the deprecated now ASMX web services you would add a method that will take as parameter the class you need:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DoSomething(Person p)
{
    ...
}
```

If you are using WCF which is the recommended technology to build web services in .NET you would design a service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomething(Person p);
}
```

In both cases in order to consume the service you will generate a strongly typed proxy on the client. Once again the recommended is to use Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio to generate a strongly typed proxy by pointing it to the WSDL of the web service. Then you will invoke the method:

```
using (var client = new MyServiceClient())
{
    Person p = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "john",
        LastName = "smith"
    };
    client.DoSomething(p);
}
```

And if your client is built on pre-.NET 3.0 you will need to use the Add Web Reference dialog in Visual Studio to generate the client proxy.

Comment: I am using ASMX.                                         'TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(obj.Multiply(Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)));'. **Multiply** is a function in my webservice. Now i want to pass a class object to Multiply function

Comment: @DavidJohn, well you will have to start by modifying Multiply web service method so that it takes the desired object as parameter instead of 2 double values that it currently does. Once you have done this you will have to regenerate the client proxy so that the new method signature is reflected and you can use it.

Comment: @DavidJohn Change your web service Multiply method to accept class and updated the web service references. then you can parse the object of new class to your web service method

Comment: What should i change in my Multiply function to accept class object.I don't know what change it requires. Thats why i am asking your help.

Comment: @DavidJohn, look at the example I wrote in my answer. You could define it like this: `public void Multiply(SomeObject o)` where `SomeObject` is a class that you have to define in your web service containing the properties you need.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd agree that the *recommended* method is to use Add Service Reference, at least not to generate the entire schema... at least under WCF, it's usually a better idea to put service and data contracts in a shared assembly. You can still generate a client proxy if you want, but it's only a few lines of code to create a `ChannelFactory<T>`.

Comment: my webservice is a remote one. Can i write simply SomeObject class object in my webservice?

Answer (score 0):

If you define class 'Bill' in your web service you will be able to use it both in you web app and in web service.
I'm not sure if there is a way to use classes that were defined in app on web service but I think it's not.

Comment: @DavidJohn Your entities should exist separately from your tiers.  Objects being passed around will need to be referenced from every tier and therefore all of your tiers will have a dependency on the entity class library.